# Do we use a comma before "as"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Can we use a comma before "as", if it comes in a second clause?

> Cpec will stabilize the economic sector of Pakistan, as it is a flagship project of BRI.

Or

> Cpec will stabilize the economic sector of Pakistan as it is a flagship project of BRI.

Which one is correct when it comes to punctuation?

Comment: If you wish the reader to pause after **Pakistan**, insert the comma. If you think the sentence should be read straight through, omit it.

Comment: I will tell you that my English teachers in high school and college (native speaker in the US) always corrected me for using "as" in this context, insisting that I use "since," since that is the meaning I (and you) was actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Cpec will stabilize the economic sector of Pakistan, as it is a flagship project of BRI.

When a dependent clause follows an independent one, a comma is usually not needed between them.

[Owl Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html#:%7E:text=Use%20commas%20after%20introductory%20a,%2C%20since%2C%20when%2C%20while.) explains.

> don't put a comma after the main clause when a dependent (subordinate) clause follows it (except for cases of **extreme contrast**)[emphasis added]

> CORRECT: She was still quite upset, **although** she had won the Oscar. (This comma use is correct, because it is an example of extreme contrast.)[emphasis added].

Your example does not present such a contrast and hence does not need a comma.

*since* and *as* are similar in this context, and both could be used to form the subordinate clause.  A difference between them is the use of commas.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-because-or-since) explains.

> We usually put a comma **before since** after the main clause [emphasis added]:

> I hope they’ve decided to come as
> I wanted to hear about their India trip.

> They’re rather expensive, since
> they’re quite hard to find.

Your example uses *as* and hence does not need a comma.

I sometimes use a comma for clarity if the independent clause preceding the dependent one is long.  The first clause in your example is not long and hence should not need a comma after it.